# <ul> and <li> pushing <div> downwards

Tags: css, html, menu, html-lists

I'm experiencing a problem with my `<ul>` `<li>` tags, and i'm not sure if the problem really lies inside the classes of thoose.

When i execute this code, the "menu" div gets pushed about 10px down from the parent "header" div. (odd addition information: When i put a border on my "menu" div, it doesnt push it down)

Here is my code for you to see:

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="background"></div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="headerLogo"><img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-top:42px;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <div class="menuContainer">
                        <ul id="nav">
                            <li class="forside"><a href="?p=hjem">Forside</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
html, body {
    height:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
img {
    border: none;
}
textarea{
    resize: none;
}

.background {
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-image: url('images/bg.png');
}

.page {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:1; 
}

.header {
    position:relative;
    height:192px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/header.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
}

.headerLogo{
    position:relative;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:475px;
}

.menu {
    position:relative;
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/menubg.png) 0 0 repeat-x;

}

.menuContainer {
    position:relative;
    width: 850px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:25px;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    width:850px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height:450px;
    background: url(images/content.png) 0 0 repeat-y;
}

.footer {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 141px;
    background: url(images/footer.png) 0 0 repeat-x;

}

// Menu
    ul#nav {
        list-style: none inside;
        }
        ul#nav li {
            display: inline;
            }
            ul#nav li a {
                display: block;
                height: 25px;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                float: left;
                }
                ul#nav li.forside  a{
                    width:80px;
                    background: url(images/menu/forside.png) top center no-repeat;
                    }               
                    ul#nav li a:hover {
                        background-position: bottom center;
                    }
                ul#nav li.forside2  a{
                width:80px;
                background: url(images/menu/forside.png) bottom center no-repeat;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you add the style below, then you execute.

```
ul
{
margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it helped.
I wonder why it didnt work when i put margin:0px; into my ul#nav